# username and password not working

Tags: password

I recently installed (well, tried) Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and during the setup I made a username and password and after the setup my laptop automatically restarted and asked for a username and password and when I enter then it says it's incorrect. I've tried resetting the password but its says it was unchanged. I've tried reinstalling Ubuntu again and had the same problem. Does anyone know what's going on or if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: OP says in a comment "got it working now" - voting to close as "cannot be reproduced".

Answer (score 7):

You can reset your  password by booting your system in **Recovery Mode**

- Reboot your system and select recovery mode in the grub menu.

  [image]
- In recovery mode select `Drop to root shell prompt option`. It will drpo to a root
  shell (if you haven't set the root password, otherwise you need to enter the root password.)
- Now enter `mount -o rw,remount /` so that you can remount the filesystem in read/write mode because by default in in read only mode.

  [image]
- Now enter `ls /home` , It will display the username(in case you forgot you username or not sure about it.)
- Now to reset password type `passwd your_username`.
- You will be promoted to enter new password. Enter your new password.
- Now type `exit` and reboot.